# The audio export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was > two high or too low for the video codec

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am occasionally receiving the following error when attempting to write a m4a (aac) audio file to a video using `write_videofile` with the moviepy library. I cannot isolate what exactly is causing this error because it happens rarely. I have tried specifying different audio bitrates, but it still raise an exception.

```
video = video.set_audio(AudioFileClip("asdf.m4a"))
video.write_videofile("video.mp4", fps=FPS, codec='libx264', audio_codec="aac", temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True, audio_bitrate="256k")
```

> [Errno 32] Broken pipe  MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the
>   following error while writing file temp-audio.m4a:
>
> temp-audio.m4a: Permission denied
>
> The audio export failed, possily because the bitrate you specified was
>   two high or too low for the video codec.:  IOError Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> video.write_videofile("video.mp4",
>   fps=FPS, codec='libx264', audio_codec="aac",
>   temp_audiofile='temp-audio.m4a', remove_temp=True,
>   audio_bitrate="256k")
>
> File "", line 2, in write_videofile File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
>   return f(clip, *a, **k)
>
> File "", line 2, in write_videofile File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 137, in
>   use_clip_fps_by_default return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw) File
>   "", line 2, in write_videofile File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
>   return f(clip, *a, **k)
>
> File "/var/task/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 331, in
>   write_videofile verbose=verbose)  File "", line 2,
>   in write_audiofile  File "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54,
>   in requires_duration return f(clip, *a, **k)  File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/audio/AudioClip.py", line 204, in write_audiofile
>   verbose=verbose, ffmpeg_params=ffmpeg_params)  File
>   "", line 2, in ffmpeg_audiowrite  File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/decorators.py", line 54, in requires_duration
>   return f(clip, *a, **k)  File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 162, in
>   ffmpeg_audiowrite writer.write_frames(chunk)  File
>   "/var/task/moviepy/audio/io/ffmpeg_audiowriter.py", line 122, in
>   write_frames raise IOError(error)
>
> IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe  MoviePy error: FFMPEG encountered the
>   following error while writing file temp-audio.m4a:   temp-audio.m4a:
>   Permission denied    The audio export failed, possily because the
>   bitrate you specified was two high or too low for the video codec.

Comment: I am having this problem too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running this script on an AWS Lambda instance. All of my files should have been written to `/tmp` as stated by the AWS Lambda documentation. Once all of my temporary files were written to the specified directory; FFMpeg no longer raised an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To give an example, this looked like:

```
vid_path = "/tmp/outputvideofile.mp4"
audio_path = "/tmp/myaudiofile.mp3"
finalclip.write_videofile(vid_path,fps=15, temp_audiofile=audio_path, remove_temp=True)
```